# Pulling latest changes from mercurial forked repository in a branch

Tags: version-control, mercurial, merge

Consider two repositories, production and stage. I have a branch in production repository called `stage-branch`. What I am trying to achieve is to merge latest changes from stage repository into that branch.

And everything went well, I cloned my production repository I pulled stage repository and merged under `stage-branch`.

What is unexpected though is that the `default` branch in my production repository now has been replaced by the `default` branch of the stage repository, which was not intended. I have just committed my merge changes under `stage-branch` in production repository but when I push I get a notification that there is a new head in my `default` branch.

How can I keep or revert my `default` branch to the state it was before pulling and merging?

*EDIT*: Production repository is a fork of stage repository, is it logical that the tip is getting automatically to latest revision of the pulled repository?

Answer (score 0):

When your push or pull something in Mercurial, by default everything (and not just the current active branch, as it is in e.g. Git) will be pushed/pulled. If you would only like to push or pull a specific branch, you'll have to use the `-b` option.

From `hg help pull` you'll for instance see:

```
-b --branch BRANCH [+]     a specific branch you would like to push
```

So if I understand your problem correct, it sounds like you doing a `hg pull -b stage-branch` should be the right thing to do.

Comment: Actually what I want to do is the reverse, I think, I want to push to the specific branch only.

Comment: In that case, it is the same for push: `hg push -b stage-branch`